# Using env-file in a sibling docker container

Tags: docker, mesos, siblings

I'm trying to run a container in mesos, not that that really matters. The task runner will attempt to spawn a sibling container to run my task but fails because I use `--env-file`.

I'm attempting to use a file from the host much like mounting volumes. In fact, I'd expect `--env-file` to work like `-v` does.

Anyway, the command that mesos is running can be boiled down to this:

```
docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock run --net host -v myvol/mychildvol:/myvol --env-file /etc/envfile --name mesos-task
```

Remove `--env-file` from this and it works

Importantly /etc/envfile exists on the host running dockerd but not in the mesos-slave container.

Comment: what error do you get when you are using the `--env-file` arg?

Comment: File not found. I seems like it just doesn't work as I'd expect. I assumed its behaviour would be similar to `-v` but it isn't.

Comment: The file needs to exists on each slave. If you don't want to do that then you can do something like sharing the volume using -v which has the file. Then specify the run command for the container as `bash -c "set -a; source /myvol/envfile; set +a; exec <original command>"`